# Подобрать проверочные слова к ПОДЪЕМ, ВЗЪЕРОШЕННЫЙ, ВЪЕЗЖАТЬ

Tags: проверочные-слова

Какие будут проверочные слова к 
ПОДЪЕМ,
ВЗЪЕРОШЕННЫЙ,
ВЪЕЗЖАТЬ?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Может, там не проверочные слова нужны, а нужно объяснить орфограмму Ъ?

Ъ, потому что после приставки перед Е,Ё,Я,Ю.

Answer (score 1):

Для взъ**е**рошенного - **е**ршик, **е**рш. Для въ**е**зжать - въ**е**зд, **е**здить. Ну а в слове подъем что проверять?